# Does the たり in Modern Japanese come from the Classical たり?

Tags: etymology, classical-japanese

For example, in the sentence `飲んだり食べたりした`. Does this たり have anything to do with the `-(i)tari` ending in Classical Japanese that meant the present progressive (and later semantically shifted to past, and then even later truncated to `-ta`)? As in `われ食べたり = 私は食べている`?

It seems quite similar, attaching to the 連用形 (albeit with 音便), and with the same form. The meaning is very, very different though. Are they related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does.

In Classical Japanese, たり was an auxiliary verb but in Modern Japanese, it is a  particle. The meaning and usage changed somewhat over time in that presently, it is used only in colloquial speech.

Regarding your example phrase われ食べたり, I need to mention the fact that 食べる is a modern verb; therefore, you should not combine it with the Classical auxiliary verb たり.　The Classical versions of 食べる are 食ふ・食らふ and 食（た）ぐ.

Comment: 食べる was not originally a 二段 verb 食ぶ 食ぶる? I guess I am just too stuck with modern vocab...

Comment: @user546099 [Yes](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%B6), it did come from [食ぶ](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%B6).  The verbs Tokyo Nagoya mentions are classical verbs with similar meaning rather than older versions of 食べる, strictly speaking.

Comment: So 食ぶ used to be an uncommon verb?

Comment: @user54609 You might want to ask that as a separate question, since this one is about 〜たり and not about 食ぶ.  (I recall reading that 食ぶ was originally from [賜ぶ](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E8%B3%9C%E3%81%B6), and that it became used as a 謙譲語／丁寧語 form of 食ふ・飲む because of its literal meaning, something like the modern いただく.)

Comment: Answers and comment threads like this make me want to ask a question which requires all you smart people to tell me **everything**. It's all so fascinating :D

Comment: @user54609, it might help you understand the verb ending ～たり to know that it originally arose as a contraction of the て verb ending + classical verb あり (modern ある) -- hence the older treatment of this as an auxiliary verb.  The ～たり ending of certain adjectives is similar but separate, and came about as adverbial particle と + classical verb あり.